# select com imagens (gerar as div's pelo id dinamicamente)

Tags: javascript

http://ibrc.com.br/teste/icon-select-example4.html

Estou usando um plugin que simula um select, mas com imagens. a intenção é pegar os valores de cada imagem e jogar dentro de um input de text de `name='algumvalor'` para posteriormente guardar os dados no banco. Estou tentando fazer um loop em javascript para gerar os id's automaticamente referentes ás `divs` lá do `HTML`, mas não está dando certo, apenas a última div está dando certo (mudando os valores).

Peguei o plugin nesse link:
https://github.com/bug7a/iconselect.js

Comment: Conseguiste resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tinhas alguns problemas no teu código.

Mudei a lógica do teu loop `while` e coloquei `icons` fora desse loop pois gera o mesmo conteúdo e não precisa ser corrido várias vezes.

Fiz uma versão corrigida:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var selects = 3; // numeros de selects a procurar
    var icons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function (nr) { // mapear o nome das imagens para gerar a array icons
        return {
            'iconFilePath': 'http://ibrc.com.br/teste/images/icons/' + nr + '.png',
            'iconValue': nr + ''
        };
    });
    for (var i = 1; i <= selects; i++) { // usando for não precisas de ter count ++ no while
        var iconElement = "my-icon-select" + i; // cache do ID
        var iconSelect = new IconSelect(iconElement, {
            'selectedIconWidth': 48,
                'selectedIconHeight': 48,
                'selectedBoxPadding': 1,
                'iconsWidth': 48,
                'iconsHeight': 48,
                'boxIconSpace': 3,
                'vectoralIconNumber': 5,
                'horizontalIconNumber': 1
        });
        iconSelect.refresh(icons); // importar os icons

        (function () { // isto é preciso para encapsular currentIconSelect num escopo próprio
            var currentIconSelect = iconSelect;
            $('#' + iconElement).on('changed', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var novoValor = currentIconSelect.getSelectedValue()
                var nomeCampo = $this.parent('label').attr('id');
                $("[name='" + nomeCampo + "']").val(novoValor);

                // atualizar o geral
                var todosInputs = $('input[name^="Form1"]').map(function () {
                    return this.value;
                }).get().filter(Boolean).join(',');
                document.getElementById('todasAsImagens').value = todosInputs;
            });
        })();
    }
};
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fo81twkg/

Não tinha bem a certeza se querias um input com todas as imagens escolhidas. Juntei isso no final.